# spring data elasticsearch propery to reach elasticsearch behind a reverse proxy (URI with a web context-path)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring boot 2.4.6 alongside data elasticsearch.

I would like to set my config for elasticsearch as below as the server is behing a reverseproxy that rewrites the URL.

```
spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris=https://admin-integration.hello.com/elasticsearch/api
spring.elasticsearch.rest.username=elastic
spring.elasticsearch.rest.password=blabla
```

and I get

*java.net.UnknownHostException: admin-integration.hello.com/elasticsearch/api*

How can I deal with that ?
I don't find any relevant property available in the config.
Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data Elasticsearch configuration can take a `withPathPrefix(String)` parameter (see the docs at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.4/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.configuration)

This is a Spring Boot problem, as these properties are processed by Spring Boot to setup the Spring Data Elasticsearch configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to PJ's reply, I was able to fix this

Do not use the spring boot starter but the plain spring data

```
    <!-- we use our own configuration because webpath prefix can not be provided with the stuffs below
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69030292/spring-data-elasticsearch-propery-to-reach-elasticsearch-behind-a-reverse-proxy/69031077#69031077
         https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-elasticsearch/
         https://hackernoon.com/elasticsearch-in-java-spring-boot-starter-pack-3kx330h
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        --> 
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```

Used the plain configuration

```
    @Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "lu.esante.agence.referential.elasticsearch.accessdb.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "lu.esante.agence.referential.accessdb" })
public class ElasticsearchClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Value("${my.elasticsearch.rest.prefix:}")
    private String es_prefix;

    @Value("${my.elasticsearch.rest.uris}")
    private String es_uri;

    @Value("${my.elasticsearch.rest.username}")
    private String es_user;

    @Value("${my.elasticsearch.rest.password}")
    private String es_password;
    
    @Value("${my.elasticsearch.rest.ssl:false}")
    private String es_ssl;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = !StringUtils.isEmpty(es_prefix)
                ? ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo(es_uri).usingSsl().withPathPrefix(es_prefix)
                        .withBasicAuth(es_user, es_password).withConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))                            
                          .withSocketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).build()
                : ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo(es_uri).withBasicAuth(es_user, es_password).build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
}
```

some hints:

- prefix cannot be null nor empty
- you have to specify the port. if not it will take 9200 by default

```
my.elasticsearch.rest.uris=hello.com:443
my.elasticsearch.rest.ssl=true
my.elasticsearch.rest.prefix=elasticsearch/api
my.elasticsearch.rest.username=elastic
my.elasticsearch.rest.password=
```